# Bash script variables and xmllint - validation against multiple xsd xml files - use the output for if

Tags: xml, bash, xsd, xmllint

I have been using stackoverflow for some time now but only just now registered to ask a question.

I have few xsd files and xml files which i need to validate. The validation works perfectly fine when i run xmllint command on individual file:

```
 xmllint --noout --schema Activity_date_1.xsd Activity_date_1.xml
```

I have multiple files that starts with same name but have different dates in them (e.g. Activity_19_09_2015.xml). 
How can i have a script that checks all the files and if any of them fail, display failed message individually.

I have done this but it doesn't quite do what i want unless it's one file only.

```
xmllint --noout --schema Activity_*.xsd Activity_*.xml >/dev/null 2>&1

xmllint --noout --schema Earning_*.xsd Earning_*.xml >/dev/null 2>&1
xmllint --noout --schema Rules_*.xsd Rules_*.xml >/dev/null 2>&1


OP=$?

if [ $OP -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e "\e[0;32;40mPassed Validation \e[0m"
else
    echo -e "\e[0;31;40mFailed Validation \e[0m"
fi
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you really have xsd files for every xml file? Don't you want to validate all xmls against the same xsd file?

Comment: could you please post a "ls" of the directory with the files?

Comment: Yes, there are really separate xsd files for every xml file. I am not a developer so i am not sure why or what not, but the developers do the validation manually one by one which is why i am creating a script so it checks all the file one by one itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have this working:

below is the code:

```
declare -a actdate

actdate=( $(ls xml-folder\Activity_*.xml | awk -F'Activity_' '{print $2}') )

for date in ${actdate[*]}
do
xmllint --noout --schema xsd-folder/Activity.xsd xml-folder/Activity_$date
done
```

**It's been a year and my bash skills have improved. Below is the better version.**

```
#!/bin/bash
#find xsd files and strip the prefix (xsd/) <-- this is because my xsds are under xsds directory 
xsds=$(find xsds/ -name "*.xsd" | sed 's/xsds\///g')
for f in $xsds
 do
#Stripping suffix .xsd extension
  xsd_file=$(echo $f | sed 's/.xsd/_/g')
#finding all xml files
  xmls=$(find . -name "$xsd_file*.xml")
   for xf in $xmls
    do
#running xmllint on all
      xmllint --noout --schema xsds/$f $xf
   done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass all the files to the xmllint command, wheras you want to loop over your files and pass the loop variable to the command one at a time:

Assuming the date is common to the {Activity, Earning, Rules} files:

```
for d in 19_09_2015 20_09_2015 <your dates here>; do 
    xmllint --noout --schema Activity_$d.xsd Activity_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1
    xmllint --noout --schema Earning_$d.xsd Earning_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1
    xmllint --noout --schema Rules_$d.xsd Rules_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1

    OP=$?

    if [ $OP -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -e "\e[0;32;40m$d Passed Validation \e[0m"
    else
        echo -e "\e[0;31;40m$d Failed Validation \e[0m"
    fi
done
```

Another issue with your code is that it current only considers the output of linting the `Rules` files for considering whether validation passed or failed. To fix this - do something like the following

```
for d in 19_09_2015 20_09_2015 <your dates here>; do 
    OP=0
    xmllint --noout --schema Activity_$d.xsd Activity_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1 || OP=?!
    xmllint --noout --schema Earning_$d.xsd Earning_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1 || OP=?!
    xmllint --noout --schema Rules_$d.xsd Rules_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1 || OP=?!

    if [ $OP -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -e "\e[0;32;40m$d Passed Validation \e[0m"
    else
        echo -e "\e[0;31;40m$d Failed Validation \e[0m"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks cmh, i have tried it with two files but the validation echo is only one. can i have it done individually? also, what if the dates are different?

Comment: Did you change `19_09_2015 20_09_2015 <your dates here>` to be a space separated list of your dates?

Comment: Yes I have.

for d in "2015_10_14 2015_10_15"; do
    OP=0
xmllint --noout --schema Activity.xsd Activit_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1 || OP=?!

xmllint --noout --schema Award.xsd AwardRules_$d.xml >/dev/null 2>&1 || OP=?!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, there shouldn't be quotes around the dates. Try again.

Comment: Thanks cmh for your help so far. It still shows me only one "Passed Validation" message for two files.

Comment: Works fine for me using bash. Which shell are you using?

Comment: I am using bash 

echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: Obviously I can't test it exactly because I don't have your xml files, but the validation loop works fine for me. Only thing left to check is that you've copied the code over correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For the reporting,

consider either:

Use if for every file:

```
   if xmllint ...; then 
     echo success
   else
     echo fail
   fi
```

or consider using bash's "set -e" option. Setting the "-e" option (cf. http://ss64.com/bash/set.html) with setting up a trap could like this:

```
trap '{ echo "validation failed"; }' ERR
set -e
for ...; do
  xmllint ...
done
```

When bash sees that one command failed, it will call the ERR trap and stop the program.

Another option is to create a function that does the tricky part:

```
validate_and_print_info() {
  if "@" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "successful"
  else
    echo "failed"
    # exit 1
  endif
}
```

and in your program, use it like this:

```
validate_and_print_info xmllint --noout --schema Rules_*.xsd Rules_*.xml
```

For the iteration over all files, this might work (if i understand your requirements correctly):

```
for xml_file in Activity_*.xml Earning_*.xml Rules_*.xml; do
  xsd_file=${xml_file%.xml}.xsd
  validate_and_print_info xmllint --noout --schema $xsd_file $xml_file
done
```